# Como imprimo la propiedad country en un ngFor de este array?

Tags: json, angular, typescript, array-bidimensional

Estoy trabajando en angular 9 y quiero hacer un select que me muestre la propiedad country de este JsoN

[image: Este es el Json]

[image: aqui estoy obteniendo data de el json]

ahora ya estoy obteniendo esto en consola, ahora como puedo pintar un select con la propiedad country?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ya intente varias formas de binding pero no se como acceder a una propiedad que trae mas propiedades

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hol@,puedes intentar usar `Object.values()`.

En la función `this.servicio.getArticulos` puedes agregar esto:

```
this.servicio.getArticulos().subscribe((paises:any) => {

    this.countries = Object.values(paises.data);

);
```

Esto te creara un array con los valores de data y apartir de ahi podras recorrer, bindear y coger unicamente el parametro que quieres mostrar en el selector.

Un saludo.